# Getting s3.putPublicAccessBlock "is not a function" in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

```
    const lockout = {
    IgnorePublicAcls: true,
    RestrictPublicBuckets: true
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(s3));
return await Promise.all(names.filter(()=> wsNames.shift()).map(name => s3.putPublicAccessBlock({Bucket: name, PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: lockout}).promise()));
```

Running in an AWS Lambda reports: s3.putPublicAccessBlock not a function.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)

Says otherwise. It's confusing because the permission name seems to be PutBucketPublicAccessBlock, but there is supposed to be a putAccessBlock at both the bucket and the account level. putBucketAccessBlock is rejected too.

I'm pretty sure it's no mere spelling mistake. Am I doing something equally daft?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Lambda's runtime to "nodejs10.x" seems to correct this issue.